# What is the purpose of a double point operator in Dart?

Tags: dart

What does it mean when a double point operator used in the following code?

```
var _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this)..addListener(_onTabChange);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called `cascade notation`, a syntax sugar for subsequent statements of the object.

It's equivalent of:

```dart
var _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync:this);
_tabController.addListener(_onTabChange);
```

Instead writing the object name again and again, you can sequently write the statements without breaking the object assignment.

docs: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation